# send file from flask view function invoked from js

Tags: javascript, flask, download

I want to send a static file with a Button event

from this flask view

```
@flask_class.route('/download')
def download():
    return send_from_directory('/home/ede//flask_lab/app/static/clientdata/', 
           filename="readcolumns.xlsx", as_attachment=True)
```

using an AJAX call

```
$("#getdata").on('click', ()=>
$.getJSON({url: '/download'}));
```

but I get no server response

the flask view works
with inserting a simple html download link the file gets downloaded

```
 <a href="{{ url_for('download') }}">download</a>
```

why does the flask view get not executed by the ajax function ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an excel file (*.xlsx) file using `$.getJSON()`, this will result in parsing error. Use the below code sample to log the error in console.

```
$.getJSON('/download')
   .then(function(res) {
       console.log(res);
   }).catch(function(error) {
       console.log(error);
   })
```

Comment: I get statusText: "OK", the filetyp does not resolve the problem

Comment: check the `responseText` attribute, it must be some unreadable value for .xlsx. Now try the same with a .json file and you will get a properly readable response.

Comment: the responseText is readable with a json file, but the file gets not downloaded also no server response

Comment: Do you want to see a download dialog window? try this code: `$('#getdata').on('click', function() { window.location = '/download'; });`